# How to build Dynamic Model driven form in angular 2

Tags: forms, angular, dynamic, model-driven-development

i have API which will send the field names object. 
so i need to build and dynamic model driven form using the object in angular 2.

Comment: Hi Pavan, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add a starting point in code to get a proper and quick answer to your question. See also http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dynamic-form.html# :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) first and learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example (best would be a Playground code snippet). Add Screenshots if necessary. And please add the important error message. please add code and error messages as text and not as images. format your source code if you mark all your code and tap on the `{}` button. That makes it easier for us to help you.